# How to change index position in composite indexing

Tags: database, indexing

I have compsite index on three fields that is NErrorCode, TmeRun and DteRun in a table  with name as AURORATASKS_STATUS having index position 1, 2, 3 repectively. Now i want to change the position of DteRun to 1. How i will write a SQL statement for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the existing index, and create a new one.

Standard SQL for dropping an index is

```
DROP INDEX indexname;
```

And adding a new one

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON tablename (DteRun, NErrorCode, TmeRun);
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX indexname ON tablename (DteRun, TmeRun, NErrorCode);
```

Most modern dbms have a relatively large number of options for creating indexes. It's probably worth reading about them before you try this.

Comment: @ Catcall Is it possible using Alter index command. if yes what will be the exact syntax having specified index order/ position???

Comment: @NaeemShah: It depends on your dbms. AFAIK, ALTER INDEX isn't standard SQL.